# Does find() method sanitize input?

Tags: cakephp

Given the following controller method, do I need to sanitize `$filtro` or will cake do that for me? If so, does cake have a function for that?

```
function ajax_load_games($filtro, $console_id){         
    $this->set('game', 
        $this->Game->find('all',
            array('conditions' => array('Game.game_name LIKE' => "%$filtro%"))
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Sanitize for what? SQL? HTML? XML? JSON?

Comment: cakephp find() method does an SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldnt call it sanitizing but escaping.
it will be done automatically for all find operations if you use the basic wrappers (not query() directly).

Also note:
It is done on basic save operations, as well: saveField, save, saveAll.

But you got no protection for query or deleteAll, updateAll etc!

Answer (score 0):

Cake applies sanitization to prevent SQL injections (which is what you mean, probably) in `find()` and `save()` methods if you use the proper array notation.

It says so [here in the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1183/Data-Sanitization).

Comment: Exacly, what I'm fuzzy about is if I'm protected while using the structure I posted on my question. especifically, I have a tainted variable directly into the statement. Does that comply to the proper notation?

Comment: You would have to test that by trying to save potentially malicious code. If special characters and entities aren't escaped, just call the Sanitize class manually.